# Sed or Awk (or something else) removing several columns from csv file

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have several files from tool suppliers which I need to merge together. However only a few of the columns in the csv file gets used. So I want to remove the irrelevant columns. I have used `sed` to do some other formatting on the file: `sed -i '1,4d` to delete the first 4 lines, `sed -i '/^\"/d'` to delete all lines starting with an `"`, `sed -i 's/  */ /g'` to replace multiple spaces with one space, and finally `sed -i '\$d'` to remove the last line.

For example:

```
2608577312,2608577312,"Metal drill bits HSS-PointTeq",AC,"Metal drill bits HSS-PointTeq","HSS PointTeQ 17,0 mm (reduced shank)",197,,102.78,,102.78,,102.78,,,,
06019H2100,06019H2100,"Drill Driver","BE ","Bosch Go","3.6V, 5/ 2.5 Nm, 360 rpm, inbuilt battery",1149,1,819.2869565217393,3,789.313043478261,10,759.3391304347826,,0,0,
06019K30K1,06019K30K1,"Drill Driver","BE ","GSR 185-LI (1 bat.)","18V, 1x 2.0Ah, 50/21 Nm, 35/10mm, brushless, Case",2399,1,1710.5913043478265,5,1648.0086956521743,20,1585.426086956522,,0,0,
06019K7020,06019K7020,"Drywall Screwdriver","BE ","GTB 185-LI","18V, 2x 2.0Ah, max. screw 6mm, brushless, reversible depth gauge, case",4699,1,3350.5913043478267,2,3228.0086956521745,4,3105.426086956522,,0,0,
06019G81K2,06019G81K2,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 120-LI + 23 pc acc","12V, 2x 2.0Ah, 30/14 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 20/10/8mm, case",2049,1,1461.026086956522,4,1407.5739130434783,8,1354.121739130435,,0,0,
06019F83K6,06019F83K6,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 180-LI (1 bat.)","18V, 1x 2.0Ah, 54/21 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/10/10mm, case",1799,1,1423.5565217391306,6,1376.626086956522,20,1314.0521739130436,,0,0,
06019F83K0,06019F83K0,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 180-LI","18V, 2x 2.0Ah, 54/21 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/10/10mm, case",2799,1,1995.8086956521743,4,1922.7913043478263,10,1849.7739130434784,,0,0,
06019K31K1,06019K31K1,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 185-LI (1 bat.)","18V, 1x 2.0Ah, 50/21 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/10/10mm, brushless, case",2599,1,1853.2,6,1785.4,12,1717.6,,0,0,
06019K31K2,06019K31K2,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 185-LI + 23 acc","18V, 2x 2.0Ah, 50/21 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/10/10mm, brushless, acc., case",3399,1,2423.634782608696,5,2334.9652173913046,10,2246.295652173913,,0,0,
06019H5100,06019H5100,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 18V-50","18V, 2x 2.0Ah, 50/28 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/13/13mm, brusless, case",3999,1,2851.4608695652178,6,2747.139130434783,12,2642.8173913043483,,0,0,
06019H5101,06019H5101,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 18V-50","18V, 2x 5.0Ah, 50/28 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/13/13mm, brushless, L-Boxx",7199,1,5133.200000000001,3,4945.400000000001,6,4757.6,,0,0,
06019K6106,06019K6106,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 18V-90 C ","18V, 2x 5.0Ah, 64/36 Nm, drilling (wood/steel) 68/13mm, metal chuck, brushless, connectivity, L-Boxx",9399,1,6701.895652173914,3,6456.7043478260875,6,6211.513043478261,,0,0,
06019F0001,06019F0001,"Impact Driver","BE ","GDR 120-LI","12V, 2x 2.0Ah, 100 Nm, 1/4'' Internal hexagon, case",2499,1,1781.895652173913,3,1716.704347826087,6,1651.513043478261,,0,0,
06019G5223,06019G5223,"Impact Driver/Wrench","BE ","GDX 180-LI","18V, 2x 2.0Ah, 180 Nm, 1/4'' Internal Hexagon / 1/2'' Square, case",3999,1,2851.4608695652178,3,2747.139130434783,6,2642.8173913043483,,0,0,
06019G61K0,06019G61K0,"Impact Wrench","BE ","GDS 250-LI ","18V, 2x 4.0Ah, 250 Nm, 1/2'' Square, case",5599,1,3992.330434782609,2,3846.2695652173916,4,3700.208695652174,,0,0,
06019K0020,06019K0020,"Impact Wrench","BE ","GDS 18V-400","18V, 2x 5.0Ah, 400 Nm, 1/2'' Square, brushless, case",7699,1,5489.721739130436,3,5288.8782608695665,6,5088.034782608696,,0,0,
06019J8502,06019J8502,"Impact Wrench","BE ","GDS 18V-1050 H","18V, 2x 8.0Ah ProCore, 1,050 Nm, 3/4'' Square, biturbo, brushless, L-Boxx",13999,1,9981.895652173915,2,9616.704347826088,5,9251.51304347826,,0,0,
06119231K0,06119231K0,"Rotary Hammer","BE ","GBH 187-LI ","18V, 2x 5.0Ah, 2.4 J, drilling Ã˜ (concrete/steel/wood) 24/13/30 mm, brushless, connectivity, case",10699,1,7628.852173913045,2,7349.7478260869575,3,7070.64347826087,,0,0,
061190600A,061190600A,"Rotary Hammer","BE ","GBH 36 V-LI Plus","36V, 2x 6.0Ah, Max drilling in concrete: 28 mm, SDS-Plus, 3.2 J, case",17699,1,12620.15652173913,2,12158.44347826087,3,11696.730434782608,,0,0,
06019H9021,06019H9021,"Angle Grinder","BE ","GWS 180-LI ","18V, 2x 4.0Ah, 11000 rpm, 125mm, M14, brushless, case",5799,1,4134.939130434783,3,3983.6608695652176,6,3832.3826086956524,,0,0,
06016B0072,06016B0072,Router,"BE ","GKF 12V-8 (solo)","12V, 13 000 rpm, includes a 1/4"" collet",2999,1,2138.4173913043483,2,2060.1826086956526,4,1981.9478260869566,,0,0,
06014A1100,06014A1100,Light,"BE ","GLI 18V-300","18V, LED, 300 lumen, 300 min/Ah",749,1,534.0695652173914,3,514.5304347826087,6,494.99130434782614,,0,0,
0601446400,0601446400,Light,"BE ","GLI 18V-1900 ","18V, LED, 1,900 lumen, 100 min/Ah ",1899,1,1354.0695652173915,2,1304.5304347826088,5,1254.9913043478261,,0,0,
06019F5100,06019F5100,Blower,"BE ","GBL 18V-120","18V, 17000 rpm , 120 mÂ³/h",1149,1,819.2869565217393,3,789.313043478261,5,759.3391304347826,,0,0,
06019D0200,06019D0200,"Orbital Sander ","BE ","GSS 18V-10","18V, sanding sheet, width 115mm, 22 000 opm",1499,1,1068.8521739130435,3,1029.7478260869566,5,990.6434782608696,,0,0,
06019C6200,06019C6200,"Vacuum Cleaner","BE ","GAS 18V-1","18V, 0.7l container volume, 10 l/s",1499,1,1068.8521739130435,3,1029.7478260869566,5,990.6434782608696,,0,0,
06019H9022,06019H9022,"Angle Grinder","BE ","GWS 180-LI","18V, 115 mm, 11000 rpm, M14, brushless",1799,1,1298.408695652174,6,1259.3000000000002,20,1220.1913043478262,,0,0,
06019K3183,06019K3183,"Impact Drill","BE ","GSB 185-LI ","18V, 50/21 Nm, drilling (wood/steel/masonry) 35/10/10mm, brushless, case",1799,1,1282.7652173913045,3,1235.8347826086958,5,1188.9043478260871,,0,0,
06019G5226,06019G5226,"Impact Driver/Wrench","BE ","GDX 180-LI","18V,180 Nm, 1/4'' Internal hexagon / 1/2'' Square holder",2199,1,1567.9826086956525,3,1510.617391304348,5,1453.2521739130436,,0,0,
06013A5020,06013A5020,"Random Orbital Sander","BE ","GEX 185-LI ","18V, sanding pad dia. 125mm, Orbit dia. 2.5mm, brushless",2199,1,1567.9826086956525,3,1510.617391304348,6,1453.2521739130436,,0,0,
06119111K0,06119111K0,"Rotary Hammer","BE ","GBH 180-LI","18V, Max drilling in concrete: 20 mm, SDS-Plus, 2 J, brushless",2699,1,1947.9739130434782,4,1889.3,10,1830.626086956522,,0,0,
06019K7021,06019K7021,"Drywall Screwdriver","BE ","GTB 185-LI ","18V, max. screw 6mm, reversible depth gauge, brushless, case",2999,1,2138.4173913043483,3,2060.1826086956526,6,1981.9478260869566,,0,0,
06019K0021,06019K0021,"Impact Wrench","BE ","GDS 18V-400","18V, 400 Nm, 1/2'' Square, brushless",2999,1,2138.4173913043483,3,2060.1826086956526,6,1981.9478260869566,,0,0,
06015B3021,06015B3021,"Jig Saw","BE ","GST 185-LI","18V, cutting depth in wood: 125 mm, brushless, LED",2999,1,2138.4173913043483,3,2060.1826086956526,6,1981.9478260869566,,0,0,
06016A2200,06016A2200,"Circular Saw","BE ","GKS 18V-57","18V, cutting depth: 57/39mm, saw blade dia.: 165mm",2999,1,2138.4173913043483,3,2060.1826086956526,6,1981.9478260869566,,0,0,
```

The above line has 17 columns, how can I remove column 1,5 and 9

EDIT:Added a larger sample size. And yes, the columns are always consistent.

Comment: Is the CSV's structure consistent, i.e., do all lines have the same number of columns, even if some are empty, and is the goal the removal of the same columns on all rows?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with more than 4 lines of input, including lines that start with `"` and lines with multiple contiguous blanks, to demonstrate all of your needs (including what you're currently using sed for) and so we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against.

Comment: The CSV's structure is always consistent. Added a larger sample size. The sample I posted here has been formatted as described in original question (no ", no multiple spaces, last line deleted etc)

Comment: Please really think about and then post a **minimal example that demonstrates your use cases** (there are no lines that start with `"` in the input you just posted and I don't see any cases of multiple contiguous blanks), not just some pile of lines you have laying around. You shouldn't need more than 10 lines of input to do that. Make sure to show the expected output too, not just input - we can't tell if a potential solution worked or not given just input, we also need to see the expected output to diff our tool output against. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Your CSV data has fields containing embedded commas, so you'll have to use a proper CSV parser, not just simple splitting on commas.  Also, your data contains multi-byte (utf8?) characters, so you'll need to use something that can deal with them.

Both perl and [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) are good choices for this.  I'd use perl if I needed to do more processing on the CSV file before printing it or import the CSV into an SQL database (once each row is in the `$row` array ref, you can do whatever you want with it - in your case, a perl script could merge multiple source files and perhaps remove duplicate entries or clean up formatting oddities like using `''` instead of `"` for inches), and `miller` if all I needed to do was cut a few fields.

Using [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller):

```
$ mlr --csv --hi --ho cut -x -f 1,5,9  input.csv
```

Using perl and perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module:

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -CSDA -e '
    my $file=shift;
    my $csv=Text::CSV->new();
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "error opening $file:$!\n";
    while(my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
      foreach my $i (8,4,0) {splice @$row, $i, 1};
      $csv->say(STDOUT, $row)
    }' input.csv
```

NOTE: perl arrays start from zero, not one, and I'm deleting the array elements (with perl's `splice` function) in reverse order to avoid issues with the indices being renumbered as elements are deleted.

Also NOTE: `Text::CSV` is not included with perl, it needs to be installed either from a distribution package (e.g. `apt-get install libtext-csv-perl` on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu & Mint) or with `cpan`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using GNU sed (for `-i`) I assume you also have GNU awk. You can get rid of all your sed commands since you never need sed when you're using awk and just run this 1 awk script (untested due to no [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question):

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '
    (NR > 5) && (prev !~ /^"/) {
        gsub(/ +/," ",prev)
        nf = patsplit(prev,p)
        out = sep = ""
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            if ( i !~ /^[159]$/ ) {
                out = out sep p[i]
                sep = OFS
            }
        }
        print out
    }
    { prev = $0 }
' file
```

If you wanted to remove, say, columns 1, 5, 17, and 35 then just change `i !~ /^[159]$/` to `i !~ /^([15]|17|35)$/` or, if you prefer, `i !~ /^(1|5|17|35)$/`.

If you wanted to be able to pass in a list of fields to skip rather than having it hard-coded in the script then change the above to:

```
awk -v skip='1,5,9' -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '
    BEGIN {
        patsplit(skip,tmp)
        for ( i in tmp ) {
            skipFlds[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    (NR > 5) && (prev !~ /^"/) {
        gsub(/ +/," ",prev)
        nf = patsplit(prev,p)
        out = sep = ""
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            if ( !(i in skipFlds) ) {
                out = out sep p[i]
                sep = OFS
            }
        }
        print out
    }
    { prev = $0 }
' file
```

Change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` to update the input file (like `sed -i`) once you're done testing and are happy with the results.

The above requires GNU awk for `FPAT`, `patsplit()`, and `-i inplace`.

See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more info on parsing CSVs with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` to remove columns 1,5 and 9.

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^,]*,(([^,]*,){3})[^,]*,(([^,]*,){3})[^,]*,/\1\3/' input_file
2608577312,"Metal drill bits HSS-PointTeq",AC,"HSS PointTeQ 17,0 mm (reduced shank)",197,102.78,,102.78,,102.78,,,,
```

You could chain all your `sed` commands into a single one;

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '1,4d;$d;/^"/d;s/ +/ /g;s/^[^,]*,(([^,]*,){3})[^,]*,(([^,]*,){3})[^,]*,/\1\3/' input_file
```

Answer (score -1):

As selected columns are needed only, `awk` could be another good option. Here is how to select only the required columns:

Data :

```
os_user:~$ cat csv_file.csv 
Tom,Jerry,23,US
luca,brasi,55,UK
```

Selected required columns using field delimiter and print function:

```
os_user:~$ awk -F"," '{print $1","$3}' csv_file.csv 
Tom,23
luca,55
```

In `awk` indexing start from 1. In the above demo, column 1 and 3 has been printed. Also, further complex programming can be done to remove conditional lines, process data, etc.

For further details reference:
[AWK Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Edit Notes: As not mentioned in the question, I didn't realize that some column has a comma in it. Thanks to Ed Morton's comment. It needs to be handled properly and my above solution didn't consider that.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). People can't copy and paste (i.e. use) your examples

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will keep that in mind next time. @roaima

Comment: You don't need to wait for next time, you could just edit your answer now, but in any case just splitting on commas won't work as some of the quoted fields contain commas.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry I didn't realize that some column has a comma in it. I've edited and mentioned that in the edit notes. Thanks for pointing that out.